# Why does the R tag have bioinformatics in the description?

Tags: discussion

Pretty simple question, no real impact, but curious... As this post is only about the r tag, I assume this is the correct place to ask? If not please let me know.

A quick scan of other languages tags don't have these specific details in... For example, on Stack,

[r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r)

> R is a free, open-source programming language and software environment for statistical computing, bioinformatics, visualization, and general computing.

[python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)

> Python is a multi-paradigm, dynamically typed, multipurpose programming language, designed to be quick (to learn, to use, and to understand), and to enforce a clean and uniform syntax.

[c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c)

> C is a general-purpose programming language used for system programming (OS and embedded), libraries, games and cross-platform.

[java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)

> Java (not to be confused with JavaScript or JScript or JS) is a general-purpose, statically typed, object-oriented programming language designed to be used in conjunction with the Java Virtual Machine (JVM).

And we see the wiki definition,

> R is a programming language and free software environment for statistical computing and graphics supported by the R Foundation for Statistical Computing. The R language is widely used among statisticians and data miners for developing statistical software and data analysis.

There is also no mention of bio... on the official about R page, (apart from a link to Bioconductor in the bottom left) https://www.r-project.org/about.html

Comment: (To answer your question, R is used heavily in bioinformatics, and the tag descriptions are written by users of this site. So it appears in the description because the author(s) of that tag description decided it was relevant, but the author(s) of the others didn't.)

Comment: I guess the i thought of the question as should the site strive for consistency?

Comment: I think the argument would be (which I mostly agree with) that R is, by design, a domain specific language intended for statistics and related fields. The others are general purpose languages that happen to see heavy use in lots of different areas. As such, it makes sense to mention it for R, but not for the others.

Comment: I do see that, and the advantages of people in the bio field to find the tag does add validity to it, but does it seem like a bias of the user creating the tag? As there is no mention in official documentation like the R project about me section etc?

Comment: I don't think that whether or not the R tag description mentions bioinformatics or not is important enough to merit much discussion, tbh. The fact that it does is totally reasonable, and removing it wouldn't benefit anyone.

Comment: it has it because someone edited it in 6 years ago and presumably no one has disagreed with it https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1026763. prior to that it just mentioned "statistical computing and graphics" per https://www.r-project.org

Comment: Most tag descriptions and wikis are not very maintained. There probably won't be a really good rationale available for most of their contents.

Comment: Interesting reasoning "A major repository of R is the bioconductor, that is aimed for bioinformatics. So I guess it's good to introduce R as a powerful language for bioinformatics also". Seems like we should add data science to the `r` tag using that logic? which could open a can of worms etc... I agree this isn't too important, but maybe worth considering a change

Comment: it seems kind of obvious; https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/BiocViews.html#___Software lists currently 1649 packages. It is widely used in this field. Interestingly, this does not necessarily apply to other data-intensive scientific domains, I have met many other researchers such as chemists, physicists, mathematicians, none of who used R and used things like MatLab or Julia or Python simply C instead. R seems to be especially used by bioinformatics disproportionately.

Comment: "Seems like we should add data science"; what people typically think of as "data science" is really very different from the kinds of things done in Bioinformatics, especially at the domain-specific,  experiment-specific spectrum where you are working with things such as genomic or amino acid sequence, its really not comparable to traditional "data science", Bioinformatics is more like "biological data janitor"

Answer (score 3):

As the tag excerpt notes, R is a language geared mainly to help with statistics, and usually one of the bioinformatics use it for their statistics tasks (which is why some call that function bio-statistics). Now, what a language *is*, it's not information for the tag excerpt, except on cases where the thing is too obscure or easily mistaken with something else.

In the context of Stack Overflow, explaining what R is and what R is used for isn't that useful. Better to actually modify other tag excerpts to explain when it should be used. Because, at this point of time, is very difficult a user would confuse R with the 18th letter of the english alphabet.

Answer (score -5):

The actual question is rather moot since neither of these tag excerpts is really useful (or [how it should be](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214337/255554)). Nobody will use Stack Overflow’s tag excerpts to find out what R, Python, C, or any other programming language is predominantly applied for or what their typing paradigms are. That’s what Wikipedia is for. What would be useful information to be featured here is guidance when to use that tag or what to be careful about when asking questions in that tag.

For example, a for [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) it could be (note that this is fictive; I have no idea whether this aligns with the actual rules on this tag):

> For questions about the programming language Java. Do not use for questions about JavaScript, JScript, JS, Indonesia, or coffee. For questions specific to the Java Virtual Machine, use the JVM tag.

Comment: Just a note, I cut the second half of the tag descriptions, where what you are saying is stated, didn't want too much reading required, and not so relevant to the question. Maybe a short description can't hurt?

Comment: "Do not use for questions about JavaScript, JScript, JS, Indonesia, or coffee", what a useless sentence. Indonesia? Coffee? When did you see questions about those?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: It is just an example for what kind of information would be useful in that place. However, given what I have experienced with other tags and SE sites, I would be surprised if there wasn’t an occasional question about the Indonesian island or the coffee type under this tag. Telling those askers that they are in the wrong place (and cheering up some others) has some benefit. On the other hand, I am quite confident that nobody’s experience on this site got improved by getting told about Java’s type paradigms in the tag excerpt.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto [back in 2010, we had a question about Indonesia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363171/indonesia-java-international-destination) :p